# How to get EditText value

Tags: android, android-edittext, tostring

I have an editText. When i try to get it's value from an onClickListener using `editText.getText().toString()` it throws an nullPointerException. It's wierd, because the other editText gives value normally.

Here is the code:

```
 addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            itemList.add(itemNameField.getText().toString());
            itemQuantityList.add(itemQuantityField.getText().toString());
            System.out.println(itemQuantityField.getText());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            itemNameField.setText(" ");
        }
    });
```

The line `itemList.add(itemNameField.getText().toString());` works normally, but the next line throws an exception.

Here is the error log:

```
04-16 11:39:58.935    1138-1138/com.grizeldi.gShopper E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.grizeldi.gShopper.activities.ShoppingList$3.onClick(ShoppingList.java:61)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: check itemQuantityField you have initialized properly

Comment: I do this `itemQuantityField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.itemQuantityField);`

Comment: post your layout xml and more relevant code.

Comment: @grizeldi also check you have initialize itemQuantityList list.

Comment: Yep, I forgot to initialize the itemQuantityList list

Comment: @grizeldi that's the reason initialize it and try.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText ta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   String s1 = ta.getText().toString();
}
});
//then check s1 is null or not
```

Comment: please add some explanation of how and why your code solves the issue

Answer (score -1):

You are getting a `NPE` on `Line number 61` in the file `ShoppingList.java:61`

Without your entire code.

```
    itemList.add(itemNameField.getText().toString());
    itemQuantityList.add(itemQuantityField.getText().toString());
    System.out.println(itemQuantityField.getText());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The chance of NPE are 
    **Check the following are initialized properly**

```
itemNameField 
itemQuantityField
itemList
itemQuantityList
adapter
```

Comment: For downvoter, can you explain y you downvoted. I can improve myself if the answer is wrong